# R flexdashboard with two simultaneous input$map_shape_click not working

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am in the process of creating an R flexdashboard. The dashboard contains several maps for Bangladesh, which are linked to a (Highcharts) chart that is activated by clicking on a polygon (e.g. region). I am able to make it work for one page. However, if I set it up for two pages, things no longer work.

It seems that flexdashboard (at least how I set it up) is not able to handle two input$map_shape_click operations at the same time. At the moment it only works on the first page, while the map does not react on the second page although a figure is produced. I welcome any suggestions to make this work.

Below a reproducible example. Note that (1) I omitted the flexdashboard yaml in the example and (2) markdown used by stackoverflow automatically renders the first, second and third header level. They render differently when run in flexdasboard (i.e. A Large Header is a new page in flexdashboard).

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(highcharter)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)

# Get data
adm1 <- getData('GADM', country='BGD', level=1)
adm1 <- st_as_sf(adm1)

# Create dummy data.frames with link to polygon
df1 <- data.frame(NAME_1 = adm1$NAME_1,
                 value_1 = c(1:7))

df2 <- data.frame(NAME_1 = adm1$NAME_1,
                 value_2 = c(8:14))
```

## Page 1

### Column {data-width=350}

#### Map 1

```
# MAIN MAP --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
output$map <- renderLeaflet({

  # Base map
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
    clearShapes() %>%
    addPolygons(data = adm1, 
                smoothFactor = 0, 
                color = "black",
                opacity = 1,
                fillColor = "transparent",
                weight = 0.5,
                stroke = TRUE,
                label = ~htmlEscape(NAME_1),
                layerId = ~NAME_1,
                )
  
})
leafletOutput('map')  


# REGION SELECTION -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Click event for the map to draw chart
click_poly <- eventReactive(input$map_shape_click, {

  x <- input$map_shape_click
  y <- x$id
  return(y)
}, ignoreNULL = TRUE) 


observe({
  req(click_poly()) # do this if click_poly() is not null

  # Add the clicked poly and remove when a new one is clicked
  map <- leafletProxy('map') %>%
      removeShape('NAME_1') %>%
      addPolygons(data = adm1[adm1$NAME_1 == click_poly(), ],
                  fill = FALSE,
                  weight = 4,
                  color = '#d01010', 
                  opacity = 1, 
                  layerId = 'NAME_1')
  })
```

### Column {data-width=350}

#### Plot 1

```
data <- reactive({

  # Fetch data for the click poly
  out <- df1[df1$NAME_1 == click_poly(), ]
  print("page 1") # print statement to show which click_poly is used
  return(out)
  })


output$plot <- renderHighchart({
  req(data()) # do this if click_poly() is not null
  
  chart <- highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = 'column') %>%
      hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = c('A'),
               title = list(text = 'Title 1')) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = 'Value 1')) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Series', 
                    data = c(data()$value_1)) %>%
      hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>%
      hc_colors(c('#d01010'))
  })

highchartOutput('plot')
```

## Page 2

### Column {data-width=350}

#### Map 2

```
# MAIN MAP --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
output$map2 <- renderLeaflet({

  # Base map
  leaflet() %>%
    addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
    clearShapes() %>%
    addPolygons(data = adm1, 
                smoothFactor = 0, 
                color = "black",
                opacity = 1,
                fillColor = "transparent",
                weight = 0.5,
                stroke = TRUE,
                label = ~htmlEscape(NAME_1),
                layerId = ~NAME_1,
                )
  
})
leafletOutput('map2')  


# REGION SELECTION -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Click event for the map to draw chart
click_poly2 <- eventReactive(input$map_shape_click, {

  x <- input$map_shape_click
  y <- x$id
  return(y)
}, ignoreNULL = TRUE) 


observe({
  req(click_poly2()) # do this if click_poly() is not null

  # Add the clicked poly and remove when a new one is clicked
  map <- leafletProxy('map2') %>%
      removeShape('NAME_1') %>%
      addPolygons(data = adm1[adm1$NAME_1 == click_poly2(), ],
                  fill = FALSE,
                  weight = 4,
                  color = '#d01010', 
                  opacity = 1, 
                  layerId = 'NAME_1')
  })
```

### Column {data-width=350}

#### Plot 2

```
data2 <- reactive({

  # Fetch data for the click poly
  out <- df2[df2$NAME_1 == click_poly2(), ]
  print("page 2") # print statement to show which click_poly is used
  return(out)
  })


output$plot2 <- renderHighchart({
  req(data2()) # do this if click_poly() is not null
  
  chart <- highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = 'column') %>%
      hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = c('A'),
               title = list(text = 'Title 2')) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = 'Value 2')) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
      hc_add_series(name = 'Series', 
                    data = c(data2()$value_2)) %>%
      hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>%
      hc_colors(c('#d01010'))
  })

highchartOutput('plot2')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `click_poly2 <- eventReactive(input$map_shape_click`, you have `click_poly2` being the 2nd map, but you have the same `map_shape_click`, what if you made it `map_shape_click2`, hopefully flexdashboard will handle it differently as now they are 2 different maps

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself following a similar question I found somewhere else. As I am quite new to shiny and based my code on examples I found, I did not realize that 'map_shape_click' applies 'shape_click' on 'map' where 'map' corresponds with the map in output$map. As I have two maps: map and map2, the eventReactive statement for page2 should be changed into

```
click_poly2 <- eventReactive(input$map2_shape_click, {

  x <- input$map2_shape_click
  y <- x$id
  return(y)
}, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
```

Now responding to a `shape_click` on map2